# "Guessing" what side of a doubly linked list to start on

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

A bit hard to explain what I'm planning, but here it goes. I have a doubly linked list of objects which are ordered alphabetically by a member attribute called `name`. I wish to remove a Node with a specific name, but I would like to remove it in such a way that it is more likely to start looking for it on the side of the list closer to it.

So I was thinking that I would have to find the 'midpoint' between the first Node's `name` and the last Node's `name`. Then I will check to see if that midpoint is less than the name of the Node. If it is less, I will start from the tail, otherwise I will start from the head.

The problem I am having is that I am unable to convert a string directly into an int. My potential solution is this:

1. Convert each individual character in the head and tail to an int
2. Put each conversion into an int array, one array for the head, one for the tail
3. Convert each int into a string again and put them into a new array
4. Make each converted string have a length of 3 by inserting 0s into them if they have less than a length of 3
5. Add the strings in each array together
6. Convert the strings to int again and find the difference between the two ints and divide that by 2
7. Add the new value to the first Node's converted name
8. Find if this 'midpoint' is less than the name of the Node I want to remove
9. If it is, start searching from the tail
10. Else, search from the head

Is there any easier way to go about doing this?

Comment: You can't do much better than just comparing the first character that is different.

Comment: It doesn't matter from which end you start. Isn't that all of the purpose of a double linked list?

Comment: It does matter if there is less Nodes I have to iterate through by going through the tail vs the head and vice versa.

Comment: @Sythe Anyways you'll need to inspect the list items, to know that. Don't you?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ that's why I'm "guessing" what end to start on, I don't actually know where it will be in the list.

Comment: The motivation, I'm assuming, is that the doubly linked list is very large and you want to optimize average case to be better than O(n), right?

Comment: If search time is important to you, a linked list is the wrong structure.  Look into trees or hash tables instead.

Answer (score 2):

Alf's comment is realistically what you want. In order to decide which end to be on, you are getting maximum resolution by simply finding the first different character and then picking based on the midpoint.

Algorithm idea

```
list = ["apple", "banana", "orange"]
word_to_search_for = ["banana"]

index = 0
while list[0][index] == list[last][index]:
    if word_to_search_for[index] != list[0][index]:
        return "word not in list"
    ++index

spread = list[last][index] - list[0][index]
if (word_to_search_for[index] - list[0][index])> spread/2:
    start at last
else:
    start at 0
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be if (word_to_search_for[index] - list[0][index]) > spread/2?

Comment: Yeah, I think so looking at it now. Nice catch

Answer (score 1):

As others have already alluded, your main problem is that you're using the wrong data structure.  Your question shouldn't be "How do I make a double linked list operate in a manner that is distinctly unlike a double linked list?", it should be "What is the best data structure for {insert your specific use case}?".

Reading between the lines, it appears that you're after something that allows for insertions, removals and relatively high speed scans.  This leads me to suggest a Left Leaning Red Black Tree: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-leaning_red%E2%80%93black_tree

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array of pointers to some sub-set of nodes in the list, like pointers to the first, middle, and last node of a list. You could use more pointers to reduce the search time, perhaps 4 to 16 pointers. Sort of a hierarchical overall structure. The array would need to be updated as nodes are deleted (at least the pointers to deleted nodes, pick the node before or after if this happens, or shrink the array). At some point, a tree like structure would be better.